# How to find only modified records from two list with java?

Tags: java, list, object

Suppose i have two list object as below

ListObj1

```
[id=1234, type=Page, subtype=HOME, name=homepage, path=/com/test/home/HOME, version=2019, description=des],
[id=1235, type=Page, subtype=HOME, name=homepage, path=/com/test/home/HOME, version=2019, description=des],
[id=1236, type=Page, subtype=HOME, name=homepage, path=/com/test/home/HOME, version=2019, description=des],
[id=1238, type=Page, subtype=HOME, name=homepage, path=/com/test/home/HOME, version=2019, description=des]
```

ListOBj2

```
[id=1234, type=Page, subtype=HOME, name=homepage, path=/com/test/home/HOME, version=2019, description=des]
[id=1235, type=Page, subtype=HOME, name=homepage, path=/com/test/home/HOME, version=2018, description=des]
[id=1236, type=Form, subtype=CONTACT, name=contact, path=/com/test/contact/CONTACT, version=2019, description=des]
[id=1237, type=Page, subtype=HOME, name=homepage, path=/com/test/home/HOME, version=2019, description=des]
```

Help me to get added, deleted and modified record. Thanks

Comment: What seems to be the problem? What did you tried so far?

Comment: Steps to turn this mess in to a question.  Step1: define what listObj1 contains.  Step2: define what listObj2: contains.  Step3: explain what you have already done that does not work.